# remove robots txt file from google search result

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, robots.txt

Good Morning, to every one

i have my site in WordPress, initially i have purchase SSL certificate and using https version  to show in google search result.

but due to https i have seen one problem that my traffic decreases, so in order to increase my traffic again i planed to show http version in google search result, by using below code

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

After some time my all https url removed from google search result and all http url indexed in google search result.

But still i have facing one problem is that my robots txt url is still appears in google search result like below.

https://yourdomain.com/robots.txt

and

http://yourdomain/robots.txt

my https version is 301 redirected to http using above code that i have already shown.

but the above two url is still shown in google search result, google shows duplicate content issue.

can anybody show me trick to remove https robots txt file from google search result.

thanks

Comment: You can remove the robots.txt file completely.  It is not needed for search engines to index your site.

Comment: sir, my site is in wordpress, i have try to delete robots txt file from cpanel, but still robots.txt url doesn't hit 404. Can you please tell me the step to completely remove robots txt file from wordpress blog.

Comment: If robots.txt file doesn't exist, than it should be throwing a 500 Error.  Are you saying you want to throw 404 Error instead?  If so, and you want 404, than you need to create the path and you can output 404 in wordpress using php like this:  `$wp_query->set_404(); status_header(404);`

Answer (score 0):

You can inset this rule in site root .htaccess **Just below `RewriteEngine On` line to throw a 404 for `robots.txt` request:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ - [L,R=404,NC]
```

Comment: sir, above code is not working.....after adding above code in my htaccess file it does not hit 404 page.

Comment: What page is being hit?  Are you getting a 500 Error page?

Comment: @RajSuryavanshi: You have to make sure above rule is in site root .htaccess NOT in any sub-directory's .htaccess

Comment: No sir, it does not hit 500 or 404, but the url is still exist....i really don't know why....

Comment: URL will be removed from search results after few weeks. You need to make sure when you directly enter `http://example.com/robots.txt` **in browser** it generates a 404